# How to create a model with a compound key in ActiveAndroid

Tags: android, activeandroid

Does anyone know if Compound keys are supported in ActiveAndroid (http://www.activeandroid.com/). and if so how to implement them? I have searched and gone through the documentation but I don;t seem to find anything on this matter.